# how to set all products to taxable goods?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community

I have added 1000s of products to my store without set those as taxable goods. It will take more time to update each product from Store Backend. Now I want to set "Taxable Goods" in Tax class field for all products in my store. How can I set all products as Taxable Goods at once ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution using this link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/38199/

On your admin go to **Catalog> Manage Products> and click Select All**. 
On the top right you will be able to see the Mass Actions dropmenu, **select “Update attributes”** and **click the submit button** to get to the Edit mode. 
You will now be editing all your products and applying the changes to them, **scroll down on the Attributes tab** and you will be able to **find Tax class** where you just need to **check the “change” box** and **select "Taxable Goods" from the dropdown**, then **save the changes**.